# How to convert &amp; or any other encoded char using [php] to it's respective char?

Tags: php

I need to output text to a file using PHP, although some of the text has & and ½ I cannot be certain that those are the only ones because the text block is very large.  Is there a very simple way to take a string containing these sorts of encodings and convert them to their respective chars?

Example

```
$str = "It rained 2& frac12 ; inches on friday. (ignore the spaces between & and ;)
```

when written to a file I would like the text to read:

```
It rained 2½ inches on friday.
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and see if that does what you need?

Comment: @Benjy1996  That worked perfectly! Thank you! I actually had tried that, but I guess I didn't give my server enough time to rerun the script and was still looking at data from previous runs trying different approaches.  How do I make your comment the answer? I'm new here

Comment: I'll post an answer, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

[`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) should do what you need!

An example of implementation returning the decoded string would be;

```
$str = html_entity_decode($str); //decoded string
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10918289)

Comment: Apologies, but the issue was resolved in my first comment, so no expansion was required for what was a fairly trivial problem.

Comment: Edited the post, although my original post was providing a PHP function which had been used successfully and the official documentation link, not just a semi-relevant link to some external implementation XD